# GET requests works in Postman but not in Python code -error 10054

Tags: python, postman

I use Postman to send a GET request with the URL "https://www.rfi.fr/cn/", it works! and no header is even required.
But when using Python requests.get(url), ConnectionResetError(10054) is returned.

I want open the URL "https://www.rfi.fr/cn/" with Python then get the News.

Answer (score 2):

add a `user-agent` header.  this worked for me (`<response 200>`):

```py
import requests


session = requests.Session()
session.headers.update({'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

url = 'https://www.rfi.fr/cn'

r = session.get(url)
print(r)
```